# How to get visual representation of binary tree codding by javascript?

Tags: javascript, treeview, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I created a binery tree using javascript but i don't know how to print it in html i tried a lot of methods but nothings work good, can someone help me in this ?

I tried canavas but i'm not perfect in this so it's doesn't work for me , i tried to append ul and li form javascript but it's give a lot of problem.

```
class Node {
constructor(data,left= null,right= null){
    this.data = data;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}
}

// AB = Binery Tree
class AB {
constructor(){
    this.root = null;
}
add(data,i){
    const node = this.root;
    console.log(data,i);
    if(node === null){
        this.root = new Node(data);
        return;
    }else{
        const SEARCHTREE = function(node){
            if(data <= node.data){
                if(node.left === null){
                    node.left = new Node(data);
                    return;
                } else if (node.left !== null){
                    return SEARCHTREE(node.left);
                }
            } else if (data > node.data) {
                if(node.right === null){
                    node.right = new Node(data);
                    return;
                }
                else if (node.right !== null){
                    return SEARCHTREE(node.right);
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        };
        return SEARCHTREE(node);
    }
  }
};


const ab = new AB();
for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
ab.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,i);
}
console.log(ab)
```

This the tree that i get : 
[image]

Comment: how sould the tree look like?

Comment: I'm guessing you want a visual representation. Something That physically lays out the nodes and connects them?

Comment: Yes that's what i want i want to see it like a tree in the view not just in console

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thank you.
this the js file :

```
class Node {
    constructor(x,y,r, ctx, data){
    this.data = data;
    this.leftNode = null;
    this.rightNode = null;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }

  draw(){
    this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2*Math.PI); 
      this.ctx.stroke();
      this.ctx.closePath();
      this.ctx.strokeText(this.data, this.x, this.y);
  }

  getData(){
    return this.data;
  }
  getX(){
    return this.x;
  }
  getY(){
    return this.y;
  }
  getRadius(){
    return this.r;
  }
  leftCoordinate(x,y,r){
    return {cx: (x - (4*r)), cy: (y + (4*r))};
  }
  rightCoordinate(x,y,r){
    return {cx: (x + (3*r)), cy: (y + (3*r))};
  }

}

class Line {
  // Takes 
  // x,y      - starting x,y coordinate
  // toX, toY - ending x,y coordinate
  draw(x, y, toX, toY, r, ctx) {
    var moveToX = x;
    var moveToY = y + r;
    var lineToX = toX;
    var lineToY = toY - r;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(moveToX, moveToY);
    ctx.lineTo(lineToX, lineToY);
    ctx.stroke(); 
  };
}
class BTree {
  constructor(){
    this.c = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
    this.ctx = this.c.getContext('2d');
    this.line = new Line();
    this.root = null;
  }

  add(data){
    // If root exists, then recursively find the place to add the new node
      if(this.root) {
        this.recursiveAddNode(this.root, null, null, data);
      } else {
      // If not, the add the element as a root 
        this.root = this.addAndDisplayNode(200, 20, 15, this.ctx,data);
        return;
      } 
  }

  // Recurively traverse the tree and find the place to add the node
    recursiveAddNode(node, prevNode, coordinateCallback, data) {
      if(node === null) {
      // This is either node.leftCoordinate or node.rightCoordinate
      var xy = coordinateCallback;
      var newNode = this.addAndDisplayNode(xy.cx, xy.cy, 15, prevNode.ctx, data);
      this.line.draw(prevNode.getX(), prevNode.getY(), xy.cx, xy.cy, prevNode.getRadius(), prevNode.ctx);
      return newNode; 
      } 
      else {
      if(data < node.getData()) {
        if(node.leftNode === null){
          var xy = node.leftCoordinate(node.x,node.y,node.r);
          node.leftNode = this.addAndDisplayNode(xy.cx, xy.cy, 15, node.ctx, data);
          this.line.draw(node.getX(), node.getY(), xy.cx, xy.cy, node.getRadius(), node.ctx);
          return;
        }else if(node.leftNode !== null){
          return 
  this.recursiveAddNode(node.leftNode,node,node.leftCoordinate(node.x,node.y,node.r), data);
        }
      }else if(data > node.getData()){
        if(node.rightNode === null){
          var xy = node.rightCoordinate(node.x,node.y,node.r);
          node.rightNode = this.addAndDisplayNode(xy.cx, xy.cy, 15, node.ctx, data);
          this.line.draw(node.getX(), node.getY(), xy.cx, xy.cy, node.getRadius(), node.ctx);
          return;
        }else if(node.rightNode !== null){
          return 
this.recursiveAddNode(node.rightNode,node,node.rightCoordinate(node.x,node.y,node.r), data);
        }
      }else {
        return null;
      }
      }
  }

  // Adds the node to the tree and calls the draw function
  addAndDisplayNode(x, y, r, ctx, data) {
    var node = new Node(x, y, r, ctx, data);
    node.draw();
    return node;
  }
}

var btree = new BTree();
for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
  btree.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}
```

And this is html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tree center">
    <canvas id='my-canvas' width="1000" height="1000">
      Your browser doesnot support canvas
    </canvas>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="arbre.js"></script>
</html>
```

And this the css file :

```
.center {margin: auto; width: 50%;}
```